# How do I run Eclipse Oxygen from Desktop Launcher?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, eclipse

I am new to Linux Ubuntu here, and I am trying to get the desktop launcher for Eclipse Oxygen working, that way I do not have to use the terminal to open Eclipse everytime I want to use it. My eclipse directory is in my desktop folder. I have also executed the following command, as I do not want to change my PATH environment variable:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/eclipse" "eclipse" 
"/home/USERNAME/Desktop/eclipse/eclipse" 1
```

I have also tried solving this issue by saving an eclipse.desktop file in my /usr/local/share/applications/ directory (sudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop), as I thought that that would solve the issue, but I just can't seem to force Eclipse to launch from the launcher.

Here are the contents of my eclipse.desktop file, in case anyone is interested:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/USERNAME/Desktop/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

Any advice would be appreciated!
Please do not hesitate to ask for more information.

Mo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using eclipse neon on Linux Mint and here is my .desktop launcher, it starts normally.You should point Exec to your installation directory of eclipse and not /usr/bin/eclipse

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=false
Name=EclipseNeon
Exec=/home/user/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Type=Application
```

if you are not sure where your eclipse executable is you can find it with

```
sudo find / -executable -name eclipse
```

hope this is useful

Comment: [SOLVED] When I use the sudo find command, it gives me /usr/bin/eclipse, the symbol link I created, as well as /etc/alternatives/eclipse. Apparently, all I had to do was drag the Eclipse.desktop file from my /usr/local/share/applications/ directory to the desktop sidebar launcher, and it worked, but thank you, regardless!